# how to find the number of bytes in a file?

Tags: c#, file, size, byte

i am making application in C#. Here i want to find out the number of  bytes in particular file. Here i am using code as

```
using(FileStream fs=new FileStream(filename,FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read))
{
    //Here i want to find the number of Bytes.
    //Some more code.
}
```

Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [`FileStream.Length`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.length.aspx) Property.

> Gets the length in bytes of the stream.

Answer (score 12):

You can use the [`FileInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) class to get its [length](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.length.aspx) in bytes (as an `Int64`):

```
new FileInfo(filename).Length;
```